# Add Record without deleting data

Tags: plugin-development, records

I'm working on a plugin, and would like to add a new Record, I already have some records, and would like to keep the data.

Is there a way to activate a new record type, without re-installing the plugin, thus loosing the other records data?

Answer (score 2):

The Craft website has a great article on this, you can simply use migrations following this document:

https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/migrations

> If your schema changes over the life of your plugin, you can write a migration to keep existing installations updated with the latest schema. Craft automatically checks for new migrations whenever a plugin’s version number changes.

In summary, you can create the Record and define all the attributes, then create a migration that would create the new table with those attributes. This would be done in the `safeUp()` method that utilizes Craft create command:

`craft()->db->createCommand()->createTable('new_table_record_name', $attributesArray, null, true);`

When the plugin is updated, it will run the migrations and create the table.

Comment: I took a similar approach, but instead of using ```craft()->db->createCommand()``` I created an instance of the record model using the "install" scenario and then followed the lead from what plugins do when they install. So it was like

```$record = new PluginName_DataRecord('install'); 
$record->createTable();
$record->addForeignKeys();
```

Is there any advantage/disadvantage to this method?